# Replace Spaces with - in angular js data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/roles/save') }}" data-ng-app="">    
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Page-Title:</label>
       <input type="text" required value="" data-ng-model="title" name="page_title" class="form-control">                     
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label>Page-Alias:</label>
 <input type="text" value="@{{ title }}" name="page_alias" class="form-control">
 </div>
```

I am new to angular and using simple data-binding so that whenever a user enters the page title the alias gets auto generated but I want to identify the spaces and replace them with a "-" (dash) . For example: whenever the user enters Home Page I want the alias to be Home-Page and even better if it's home-page.
I tried doing this

```
 <input type="text" value="@{{title.replace(/-/g, ' ');}} name="page_alias" class="form-control">
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: On a side note, your replace syntax should be the other way round.

Comment: @xenish, did you find my answer accepted? if so, can you mark it that way?

Answer (score 4):

#### "I want to identify the spaces and replace them with a "-" (dash)"

**JS**

```
angular.module('app')
    .filter('slugify', function() {
        return function(input) {
            input = input || '';

            return input.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase();
       }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" value="@{{ title | slugify }}" name="page_alias" class="form-control">
```

#### "even better if it's home-page"

I added `toLowerCase` after the replace to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create filter for your template:

```
.filter('replacementFilter', function() {
   return function(input) {
       return input.replace(/ /g, '-');
   }
});
```

and use it:

```
 <input type="text" value="@{{ title | replacementFilter }}" name="page_alias" class="form-control">
```

Check out here:

https://jsfiddle.net/awk4ttem/2/

Comment: Your example is replacing dashes with spaces.

Comment: He/she has different description and example :). In example is trying to replace dashes with space, but in description is vice versa. If so, just replace values there.

Comment: That's because in the example, xenish says that they tried that, but it didn't work.

The post title and content indicates the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways: One using `replace within the expression` and another using awesome angular filter.

```
   <input type="text" value="@{{ title.replace('-',' ')}}" name="page_alias" class="form-control">

    <input type="text" value="@{{ title | replaceSpaceWithDash : '-'}}" name="page_alias" class="form-control">

app.filter("replaceSpaceWithDash", function() {
    return function(data, delimiter) {
       return data.replace(/\s/g,delimiter);
     }
   });
```

You can change the `delimiter` to anything which you pass to the `replaceSpaceWithDash` filter. Currently am passing `-`, you can change it later as per your need.

For making it lower case, just use the inbuilt filter `| lowercase`

So it will become:

```
value="@{{ title | replaceSpaceWithDash : '-' | lowercase }}"
```

Comment: Your first example is replacing dashes with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted on -blur of textbox you can used in this way:

```
<input type="text" required value="" data-ng-model="title" ng-blur="removeSpaces(title)" name="page_title" class="form-control">
```

Js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
$scope.removeSpaces = function(text) {   

   $scope.title =  text.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
  }
});
```

**Updated:**

```
   <input type="text" required value="" data-ng-model="title" ng-blur="removeSpaces(title)" name="page_title" class="form-control">  
   <input type="text" value="@{{ alias }}" name="page_alias" ng-modal="alias" class="form-control">
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
$scope.removeSpaces = function(text) {   

 $scope.alias =  text.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
}
});
```